# Catel and not validate on view loaded

Tags: catel

I've a login form that requires the user to enter username/password. when it first loads the 2 fields are empty so a validation error appears on both fields. Is there a way with Catel I can disable validation on viewmodel's load?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [docs](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Deferring+validation). In your vm ctor, set `DeferValidationUntilFirstSaveCall` to `true`